# Modify an Order via the API prior to Invoicing?

Tags: magento

In the default Magento 1.7 install is it possible to modify an order via the API prior to it being invoiced? I know there is no mechanism to do this in the Admin without a module but wasn't sure if the new API connections may allow this to happen.

To clarify, the idea here is someone places an order and then decided that they want to add something else to the order. Ideally I would like to push this change via the API from our other inventory system as our CSRs do not use the Magento interface to handle invoicing or shipment details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with the default Magento API. See the [Sales Order API documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html). You may hold or cancel the order but not edit its information.

If you edit an order in the Magento backend and save it, the old order is cancelled and a new order is created. These orders are recognisable by a special number format ("-[versionnumber]" is appended to the order number), see the [Managing and Editing Orders documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_8#managing_and_editing_orders1).

You may want to mimic this behaviour using the default Magento API.

- Get the information from the current order.
- Create a new cart, fill it with the corrected information and create a new order for this cart (see the [Checkout/Cart API documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/checkout.html) for necessary methods).
- Cancel the old order.

It won't be trivial, but it should be possible.